# Set max-width in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css

What I need is to set the limit of an image's width to 100% in Internet Explorer, like other browsers do with `max-width`.  That is, if the image's width is larger than the containing area's width, it scales down to fit the width of the containing area, but if it's smaller, its size doesn't change. Similarly, if the image is inside a table cell (`td`) and it's larger than the cell, I want it to scale to the size of the cell, instead of expanding it.

While there are other questions and answers that seem to be about this, I can't get any of them to work.  For example, this solution is usually suggested to emulate max-width in Internet Explorer:

http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/

In essence using this:

```
width:expression( 
    document.body.clientWidth > (500/12) * 
    parseInt(document.body.currentStyle.fontSize)?
        "30em":
        "auto" );
}
```

However, when I try it I don't get expected results at all. In some cases I get width values of -1 and no displayed image at all when I check in Firebug or something like it.

And I don't see how that solution could work either.

EDIT:

According to request, here is some sample code:

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0"
    summary="" id="Push12Matt__simpletable_rph_vch_32" border="0" class="simpletable">
    <tr class="strow">
     <td valign="top" class="stentry" width="50%">
      <div class="fig fignone" id="Push12Matt__fig_6a268fd9-2a26-474f-83f5-528ffbab70d3"><a
        name="Push12Matt__fig_6a268fd9-2a26-474f-83f5-528ffbab70d3"><!-- --></a><p class="figcap"
        >Bild 1. Uponor Push 12</p>
       <a name="Push12Matt__image_4dd4d9ef-f95c-41f1-b423-7ddd3a2b0c06"><!-- --></a><img
        class="image" id="Push12Matt__image_4dd4d9ef-f95c-41f1-b423-7ddd3a2b0c06"
        src="/handbok/images/Push12/Push12_byggmatt.jpg" />
      </div>
     </td>

     <td valign="top" class="stentry" width="50%">
      <div class="fig fignone" id="Push12Matt__fig_689a2b08-ffbb-4f92-9a27-010e99665959"><a
        name="Push12Matt__fig_689a2b08-ffbb-4f92-9a27-010e99665959"><!-- --></a><p class="figcap"
        >Bild 2. Uponor ElPush 12</p>
       <a name="Push12Matt__image_f6d7c2fa-8ab3-4e46-b79c-e7881dff03e9"><!-- --></a><img
        class="image" id="Push12Matt__image_f6d7c2fa-8ab3-4e46-b79c-e7881dff03e9"
        src="/handbok/images/Push12/Push12Electronic_byggmatt.jpg" />
      </div>
     </td>

    </tr>
   </table>
```

And the simple css (working for all browsers except IE):

```
img
{
    max-width : 100%;
    max-height : 100%;
}
```

But it doesn't work for this code in IE. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it is placed in a table, I don't know, but when I try this div example on W3Schools, it works fine:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_max-width&preval=50%25

EDIT 2:

Example full HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="sv-se" xml:lang="sv-se">
    <head>
        <title>Image test</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                max-height : 100%;
                max-width : 100%;
                width : 500px;


            }
            img {
                max-height : 100%;
                max-width : 100%;
                width : auto;
                height : auto;
            }
            td
            {
                max-height : 100%;
                max-width : 500px;
                display : block;
            }</style>
    </head>
    <body id="frontpage">
        <h1 class="title topictitle1">Image test</h1>
        <div class="body conbody">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="Push12_byggmatt.jpg" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="Push12Electronic_byggmatt.jpg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page shows the same problem. The images do not scale down to fit in the table cells. In other browsers I can resize the window as much as I want, and the images just keeps scaling down. IE8 and 9 don't. So it seems IE8 and 9 support max-width and max-height, but only for pixel values, not for percentage values - i.e. it only has partial support... If I'm correct, I'm really surprised it's so hard to find any info on this on the Internet. Everyone's just talking about these browsers as finally supporting it after IE6 didn't...

Anyway, I have written a jQuery workaround, but I would rather have not needed it. So if anyone can tell me I'm wrong and show me that IE8 and 9 actually do support max-width percentage values I'd be glad to be wrong :-)

Comment: Your question is more likely to get some answers if you provide the code you already have. As it stands, if the typical options don't work, there very well may be something interfering with the techniques, or some other conflict.

Comment: You may be right in some sense, see my edit about the W3Shools example that works. But it doesn't work in my own page...

Comment: Are you talking about IE6? Newer versions support max-width.

Comment: No, I'm talking about both IE8 and IE9, and yes, I know it's supposed to support it, but in my example above it doesn't. And the exact same code is used for all other browsers, where it works fine.

Comment: @AndersSvensson Are you sure your website is being displayed in standards mode? You should have `<!doctype html>` at the top of your markup.

Comment: I'm using IE9 and I use the built-in developer tools to switch between versions of the standard, from latest IE9 to IE8. Not compatibility mode or anything. Just browser versions. I'm on Mac OS X Lion, using Parallels to open Windows and IE. And no I don't use the HTML5 doctype, because this is a transformation from XML (done in bulk) using the DITA Open Toolkit. HTML5 is not supported there yet.

Comment: What doctype is it producing, then? Even if it's not the HTML5 one, it still needs to be a valid one that IE understands.

Comment: @Shauna: Of course. It uses the XHTML transitional doctype. I'll post a full sample HTML page so you can see. I've tested this, and I tested all your suggestions as you can see except removing the table altogether (tables are important since this is technical documentation, it's full of actual tables, not tables for layout). This simple example shows the same problem. Try it with a couple of large images if you like. I believe the problem is that while IE8 and 9 support max-width and max-height, they only do it for pixel values, not for percentages, which other browsers do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE9, at least, does support `max-width` percentages for images, but the percentage is relative to the *image's* size, not the *container's* size. (You can see this by changing `100%` to, say, `70%`.)  It will work somewhat as expected, however, if you specify `inherit` instead of `100%`.  Doing so will inherit the container's size for `max-width` in IE9.  (I've only tested your example page in IE9, Firefox, and Google Chrome, and it's not true that for that page, the images will keep scaling down as the window width gets smaller.)  This is not a perfect solution however; in IE8 browser mode, applying `inherit` this way will make the table cell's width equal to the image's unscaled width, even though the image is correctly scaled down.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had time to test it, but this is an idea that seems worth checking out, so I'll go with this answer.

Comment: I tested this out now, and unfortunately it didn't work... I suppose inherit doesn't work because there is no max-width set on the parent?

Comment: `max-width` is already set on the parent `td` element, namely 500px.  It "works" insofar as the image is scaled down to 500px, which is the size given by `max-width` on `td`.  If you say it doesn't work because the image doesn't keep scaling down as the window width gets smaller, keep in mind again that neither IE9 nor other browsers show that behavior in your test page.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason why you've put a div inside of a td?

There are two things offhand that I think may be interfering:

1. The div. If it's only there for class and ID, see if you can move that into the td element. If you can't, make sure you set its width and height properties to 100%. Letting it take on automatic dimensions may be interfering with the image sizing.
2. It may be breaking due to the nature of `display: table-cell;`, which is what `td` typically defaults to. Try changing its display to something like block or inline-block and see if that fixes the issue, then go from there (fyi - IE7 doesn't understand inline-block, but you can deal with that after you figure out what's causing the image problem).

Another alternative is to avoid tables altogether. The code you've provided suggests that you may be using a table for layout purposes, which isn't what they're meant for.

Additionally, your usage of attributes such as `cellpadding` and `valign` suggest that your references are quite a bit outdated. I highly recommend learning about more current methods and standards. [Here's an article addressing cellpadding to get you started.](http://www.quackit.com/css/css_cellpadding.cfm)

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained this: I don't actually create this html code myself (god forbid), no it's generated in an XSLT transform from the DITA Open Toolkit for technical documentation. And I have very little influence over the xml files that are the basis for the transformation. Also, I agree there is a lot that's outdated in the html code, but that is also largely out of my hands. What I do is customize a predefined XSLT transform. So I can do some changes to the output, but to change all of it would be monumental... But I'll see if any of your suggestions help in a test file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting `max-width: none` resolved an issue in my case.

**Note:** tested on IE11