# Resize image according to parent width jQuery

Tags: jquery, width

I am trying to scale images to fit within their parent element width, and especially for images located in tables.

The problem was that different browsers and platforms seem to behave differently when it comes to determining the width of the parent element.

So I tried to get the width of the parent td element in `$(document).ready`:

```
$('td').each(function () {
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this).width(width);
});
```

And then in `$(window).load` (when the images should be loaded) I try to set the width of the images according to the width css style of the td:

```
var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
if ($(this).closest('td')) {
    parentWidth = $(this).closest('td').css('width').replace('px', '');
}
```

But this seems to be unreliable. It works sometimes, and in some browsers, but sometimes it fails miserably, giving the wrong value for the `td` width.

I want to be able to get the width of the `td` before the images are loaded, so that the width isn't distorted by the images expanding it.

Of course, none of this would have been necessary, if it wasn't for IE8 and below not supporting max-width and max-height, but it doesn't.

How can I do this and get the parent widths before images are loaded?

BTW: the `td` can have a width percentage value to start with in a 100% width table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
if ($(this).closest('td'))
```

closest returns a jQuery object with 0 or 1 element.  You probably mean:

```
if ($(this).closest('td').length == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-), IE 7 and IE 8 do, in fact, support max-height and max-width. It's only IE 6 that can't (and there are a number of workarounds documented that may suit your purposes, as well as IE's conditional comments that can be used to sandbox any code needed to make any given version of IE behave).

Have you tried simply using `width: 100%;` in the CSS for your image? It should work on all browsers, and removes the need for a bunch of JavaScript, as long as you're setting the width of the parent element(s) on load (if you're changing the width after load, you may need a little bit of JavaScript to "refresh" the image's size, but it should be considerably less than what you're doing now).

Comment: Well, setting the width to 100% doesn't work, since some images are too large, so they overflow. That's why I need max-width. As far as I know it doesn't work, at least if you set it to 100%. But you're welcome to answer that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645087/set-max-width-in-internet-explorer where there's a bounty for this problem. I'll try it out again, but it didn't work last time I checked.