# Internet Explorer - <img> width not taking effect?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have an issue in IE9 with IMG width, it can be seen here, http://ncms.us/ncms/admin/login the only issue I see is that I'm using ' instead of " for my tags because its within a PHP echo. The main picture up at the header is huge on IE (IE9+IE10 tested.) looks fine in everything but IE. Here is the code that is throwing IE off. I can see why, its very complex and nothing its seen before (-_- lol)

```
<img style='margin-top: -25px;' src='img/ncms_logo.png' width='300' height='250' />
```

Yay for IE!

Comment: This may also be of interest. With regard to the use of max-width 100% on images with IE9. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645087/set-max-width-in-internet-explorer#answer-8854588

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like in your bootstrap.min.css there is a default class from img. that has the property width:auto;

If this is removed it will display properly in IE.

Additionally just adding

```
 width: 300px;
```

in your style along with the margin, will correct the issue.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in my blindfolded quest for IE fixes :P