# Image width ignored

Tags: image, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, width

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span8">
          <img src="img/logo.svg">
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <img class="img-circle" src="<? echo $FOTO;?>" width="35px">
            <span class="nome-user"> Bem vindo, <? echo $NOME_SOBRENOME; ?></span>
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-warning">SAIR</button></div></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- fecha container -->
</div><!-- fecha o header -->
```

Hi, I tried to search this issue but nothing worked for me. I'm using bootstrap.
IE9 ignores my width definition on the `img` tag. I tried `width="35"` and `width="35px\9"`.

Comment: can you make it of fiddle?

Comment: do you find the same problem here: http://bootply.com/65371? it works fine in ff and chrome. Maybe also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

Attribute sizing of the image is not recommended.

You better use server-side sizing or CSS, not size attributes. **Always avoid** inline style too.

More, take a look at this [question about `img` width with IE9 and Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694837/internet-explorer-img-width-not-taking-effect).