# How to make a fixed table which allows you to handle overflow and vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

Forgive me if I went a little nutty with the heights and widths (I was just randomly trying stuff).

1. Check this out:

https://jsfiddle.net/dddrbw89/

```
<body style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: white;">
    <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <tr style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
                <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden">
                    just some text.
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 10%; height: 100px;">
                <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden">
                    some more text, just a little bit more than the other cell. I'm looking for some overflow to this thing.
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
                <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden">
                    just some text.
                </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

This is close to what I want.  The table width is fixed (in this case 100), and the the table height is fixed.  The text stays within the cells without overflowing.  But, the text won't align at the bottom.

2. Fine, let's remove *just* the div tags around each text (that's what I was using to handle overflow):

https://jsfiddle.net/9qpaLn5a/

```
<body style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: white;">
    <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <tr style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
                just some text.
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 10%; height: 100px;">
                some more text, just a little bit more than the other cell. I'm looking for some overflow to this thing.
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
                just some text.
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Well, once I remove the div tags, the table expands to the height of the text (so no longer fixed at 100px).

The first link (#1) handles overflow, but I can't get the text aligned at the bottom of the cell.

The second link (#2) handles overflow - as in there won't be any - because it increases the height of the table.

I can't seem to get a combination of the both.  Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually entirely possible with the power of flexbox! Simply take the first of your two attempts, and apply the following to the container div:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
```

```html
<body style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: white;">
  <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <tr style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          just some text.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 10%; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          some more text, just a little bit more than the other cell. I'm looking for some overflow to this thing.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          just some text.
        </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I've also created a Fiddle of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/2m9e9rmk/1/).

If you'd like to have the central column overflow at the **bottom**, simply replace `align-items: flex-end`, with `align-items: flex-start` on the middle column, as such:

```html
<body style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: white;">
  <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <tr style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          just some text.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 10%; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-start;">
          some more text, just a little bit more than the other cell. I'm looking for some overflow to this thing.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          just some text.
        </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**EDIT**:

Keep in mind that Internet Explorer is terrible at handling tables, and will not respect your percentage-based widths. The best way to get around this is to set a pixel-based **`max-width`** equivalent to the relevant widths. This will **force** the browser to not expand your cells:

```html
<body style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: white;">
  <table style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <tr style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; max-width: 45px; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          just some text.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 10%; max-width: 10px; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-start;">
          some more text, just a little bit more than the other cell. I'm looking for some overflow to this thing.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:center; border-style: solid; width: 45%; max-width: 45px; height: 100px;">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          just some text.
        </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Also keep in mind that you should be making sure that your percentage-based totals add up to 100%, as most browsers will try to 'correct' that for you automatically ;)

**EDIT 2**:

You were very close with your final attempt, but missed two things: your middle column was using `align-items: flex-start`, when it should have been using `align-items: flex-end`. The second step was to add **another** div **inside** the flexbox div, which you can center with `margin: 0 auto`:

```html
<body style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: white;">
  <table style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    <tr style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; border-style: solid; width: 45%; max-width: 180px; height: 400px;">
        <div style="height: 400px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
            just some text.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; border-style: solid; width: 10%; max-width: 40px; height: 400px;">
        <div style="height: 400px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          <div style="margin:0 auto;">
            some more text, just a little bit more than the other cell. I'm looking for some overflow to this thing.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom; border-style: solid; width: 45%; max-width: 180px; height: 400px;">
        <div style="height: 400px; overflow:hidden; display:flex; align-items:flex-end;">
          <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
            just some text.
          </div>
        </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I've also created [this new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/rbn0devo/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is close, and I'll have to look into flexbox, but if you notice, it completely ignores my percentages of 45%, 10%, and 45% for each of the cells.  The middle cell should basically be a sliver in this example.  You can change the percentages to anything, and it will always display the same (in Edge and Firefox - from my testing).  In fact, in IE11, it completely ignores the fact that the width of the table should be 100.  It just expands the table as far as it can so all the text lays flat, aligned at the bottom, so that every bit of text is displayed.

Comment: You mentioned not to worry about your heights and widths, but fortunately the width problem isn't caused by flex -- it's caused by the fact that IE is terrible at handling tables. To get around this, simply set a pixel-based **`max-width`** equivalent to the relevant widths -- https://jsfiddle.net/tfquup9p/1/. You also should be making sure that your percentage-based totals add up to 100%, as most browsers will try to 'correct' that for you automatically ;)

Comment: Actually, I was just saying that I might have overused them.  But I did want a fixed table in the header (that meant fixed width).  I got pulled away for demo-server issues, but before that, I think I came up with a solution that didn't involve flexbox.  I think it was as simple as not having table-layout: fixed (which I thought I had tried).  Let me go confirm that this does actually work!

Comment: Guess I was wrong about mine.  Still a glitch.  I don't think your latest (in the comments) is either.  You can't tell, because the example is 100 width and 100 height, but I took your same code and made the table 400 width and 400 height (and I increased the max-width too, at scale) ... https://jsfiddle.net/1e2L53c2/  ... none of the text is centered and the middle cell is at the top.  all three cells were supposed to be bottom/center.  There has to be a way!

Comment: There certainly is a way! I've just updated my answer again to cover this. See `Edit 2` :)

Comment: Cool.  I do have a slimmed down version that doesn't need flexbox and not as many style elements as I have littered all over this table, BUT ... there's one annoyance.  I'd like the text to fill the whole cell if it could.  Where in my example (set to center - bottom), the text just stays on one line (but doesn't overflow).  To me, if there's more text to show, push the text up (starting from center-bottom) until it reaches the top of the cell!  Argh. So close.

Comment: I did see your edit2.  Very nice.  And that does work for fixed-width tables.  But, for tables where I want the width to be 100% (that's actually what I'm striving for), your code still works (in Firefox and Edge), but not in IE11.  In IE11, the middle cell just makes itself as big as it needs to be to fit everything.  And the reason it doesn't work is, I think, because of the max-width.  When we were using fixed width, I could just do some calculations (300 width table, I want this cell 10%, so make the max-width: 30px!). ... comment continued below ... I'm running out of room ...

Comment: But with 100% width, I just made the max-width % equal the width % for the cell - and it didn't work at all.  I'm going to give you a green check mark for being so awesome, but geesh can this stuff be maddening - being that I'm still working on this.

Comment: Good luck with the process, though I'm pretty stumped myself with the IE bug! I found out that a percentage-based `max-width` will work in IE if applied to the inner DIV, though it doesn't seem to work with the table cells. You might be able to find something helpful based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854588/2341603). I'll have a bit of a play around, and let you know if I come up with anything further :)

Comment: Btw, I did finally figure it out using html tables.  I had started another thread here asking a different question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844881/why-does-my-div-table-lose-its-bottom-border-upon-sizing/42910400#42910400