# Why does my div table lose its bottom border upon sizing?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle located here: https://jsfiddle.net/9me1rrLm/

```
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%;">
<div style="height:50px;  overflow:hidden;">
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 10%; vertical-align: top;">
        0002
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 40%; vertical-align: middle;">
        Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 30%; vertical-align: bottom;">
        Robotin'
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 20%; vertical-align: bottom;">
        need@input.com
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

When the browser is somewhat to mostly expanded, no problems:

[image: Image 1]

See, after shrinking the browser, so mostly expanded, still no problems:

[image: Image 2]

Then, after shrinking the browser as far as I could, I lose text and the bottom border:

[image]

Why? I don't want to lose the border, and I want as much text as possible to stay within the cell (with the overflow invisible).

Thank you.

**EDIT1:** Just for clarification, I don't want to remove overflow hidden or the height of the table to increase.  Keeping that is what what makes this question difficult.  For example, I have the same fixed height and overflow here and it works perfect , except for the fact it ignores my vertical alignment.  So I now have two versions.  One causes the border to disappear, the other loses it's vertical alginment (but allows text alignment):

https://jsfiddle.net/2L0cggds/

```
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%;">
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 50px;">
    <div style="display: table-row; width: 100%; height: 50px;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 10%;height: 50px; border-style: solid;">
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height: 50px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">
        0004
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 40%;height:50px;border-style: solid;">
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:50px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">  
        Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 30%;height: 50px; border-style: solid;">
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height: 50px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">
        Robotin'
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 20%;height:50px;border-style: solid;">
        <div style="overflow:hidden; height:50px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">  
        need@input.com
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT2:** I know this is possible because I see this done in Visual Web GUI.  This took me minutes in Visual WebGUI (and hours with html/css with no end in sight!)  Take a look and see how the border didn't disappear and the text stayed within the cells:

[image]

And here is the div madness I look at when I view source (it's like div within a div within a div ... and I could only expand and show to the point where we see my first cell ... and I highlighted the 50px):

[image: vwg image 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to exactly what I want.

I ditched the div tables and used regular html tables (more on that later) - I think I was influenced by what the "cool kids" are doing, but I like results, and I have it working in html tables, so there's no need that I can see to force this to work nicely with div tables.

It also required tables within tables.

Anyhow, here's something that works perfectly:

https://jsfiddle.net/99qz9okk/

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100px; table-layout:fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-style: solid; width: 10%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: left;"> <!-- vertical-align needs to be here, it seems -->
            0001
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="border-style: solid; width: 40%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">
            Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five! Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five? Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five!!
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="border-style: solid; width: 30%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;">
            Robotin'
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="border-style: solid; width: 20%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
            need@input.com
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That, just works.  I can keep the height fixed (it won't increase).  Text overflow does not expand beyond the cell it is in.  I don't lose the bottom border.  I can align the text vertically and horizontally.  Perfect.

Not that I'm an absolute noob, but I haven't dabbled in html/css recently (more C++, C#, back-end, etc).  But as I mentioned, the "cool kids" have been talking about div's, but I haven't found a solution when using div tables - or it's much harder or I'm missing something in some way.  And this is where my lack of understanding comes in, I suppose, but hey, why not try my "html table" solution and just replace:

- table with div display: table;
- tr with div display: table-row;
- td with div display: table-cell;

Well, that doesn't exactly work, so, oh well!  For now, I don't like you div tables!!

For ha ha's:

https://jsfiddle.net/8goq3hkv/

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100px; table-layout:fixed;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 10%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: left;"> <!-- vertical-align needs to be here, it seems -->
            0001
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 40%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">
            Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five! Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five? Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five!!
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 30%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;">
            Robotin'
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 20%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
            need@input.com
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of this code which wraps your table:

```
<div style="height:50px;  overflow:hidden;">
```

The table gets higher. i.e. its lower border goes down, but the wrapping div (see above) hides the overflowing part.

If you nevertheless want a bottom border, just apply it to this wrapping div:

https://jsfiddle.net/q3rxj91p/1/

Comment: Close, kind of (bottom border much thicker), but I lose the text in cell 3 and cell 4 that are aligned to the bottom.  I know this is possible, I'm staring at HTML generated by VWG that achieves this!  I'm so close!

Comment: so why don't you align the text to the top? The bottom is hidden by your `overflow: hidden` rule (https://jsfiddle.net/q3rxj91p/3/)

Comment: Because I want to have the ability to put the text anywhere in the cell.  It could be vertically aligned top, middle, bottom, and text-aligned left, center, right.  I am giving the users the ability to generate a simple web page, for a certain utility.  So I am putting together a sort of designer that allows them a header, a body, and a footer.  This would be part of my header where I allow (in the header) just an image, just text, or both (so the table would expand to two columns with "both").  The text can then be placed above, left, right, below the image.  Text can be aligned as they wish

Comment: In other words this is something that should be configurable to meet the end-users needs (not my needs).  I was able to make a fixed header that exhibits none of the issues I see here (losing bottom border and overflow escaping the cell) ... BUT ... when I do it like that I lose the ability to vertically align the text in the cell.  That code was here and never got a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798355/how-to-make-a-fixed-table-which-allows-you-to-handle-overflow-and-vertical-align/42798554#42798554

Comment: So I'm even closer now.  If I could combine the two ... great!  I'm so close.  But there's always some annoying "feature" that pops up, no matter what I do it seems ... unless I become the genius behind Visual WebGUI, as they were able to create a designer in Visual Studio that allows you to drag/dop, fix items, dock fill, etc. and it comes out perfect.

Comment: Figured it out.  Ditched div tables and used html tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have set a height on one of the containers to `50px` so it's cutting the table off at the bottom when the text wraps and makes the cells bigger.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/984u9ok7/)

```
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%;">

<!-- REMOVE THE HEIGHT ATTRIBUTE FROM THIS DIV -->
<div style="height:50px;  overflow:hidden;">

<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 10%; vertical-align: top;">
        0002
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 40%; vertical-align: middle;">
        Johnny Five Johnny Five Johnny Five
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 30%; vertical-align: bottom;">
        Robotin'
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; border-style: solid; width: 20%; vertical-align: bottom;">
        need@input.com
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: My apologies.  I don't want the table to increase in height (this is going to be a header that I want at a fixed height) and if they do size it to the point that all the text doesn't fit, I'm OK with displaying as much as I can and the remainder (the overflow) being hidden.  That's what makes this hard and why I reached out.  I know this is possible as I've seen this.  I will add some pics of some Visual WebGUI code that does what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Figured it out.  Ditched div tables and used html tables.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline style of overflow:hidden or adjust the height of the container.

Comment: But I'd like the container to be a certain height, and I don't want text spilling out of the cell.  They are necessary.

Comment: Then I would suggest using media queries to adjust font size or make the width of the columns wider. If the line breaks on a word its going make the columns longer.

Comment: I'm trying to re-create something I see in my Visual WebGUI code, and I'm certain they don't do what you suggest.  Yet, they are able to.  But there is sooooo many div containers and css classes, I can't follow the source.

Comment: Maybe they are re-scaling the entire table, difficult for me to tell without an example.

Comment: I posted some screenshots, it's some serious div's going on in there.

Comment: I would agree with Johannes answer.

Comment: The text that's aligned to the bottom (last two cells) still falls out of the cell and disappears with his solution.  It seems like with VWG they have tables within tables, so maybe I need to do something like that, but I've tried that.  My goodness hand-crafting html/css stinks!  Yet in Visual WebGUI, I can craft this stuff in seconds and it will be browser independent.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you're looking for now. That is tricky, I'll edit my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: Figured it out.  Ditched div tables and used html tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the table is being displayed in a `div` that has its `height` explicitly set to a value that isn't big enough when the page is shrunken down and that `div` has `overflow:hidden` set on it:

```
<div style="height:100px;  overflow:hidden;">
```

Remove the `overflow:hidden` and that won't happen. See **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/owon0d3t/1/)** for modified working version.

You could also set `overflow:scroll` to keep the overall height and allow users to see all of the overflowed table. See **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/acce88yh/1/)** for that.

Comment: My apologies.  I don't want the table to increase in height (this is going to be a header that I want at a fixed height) and if they do size it to the point that all the text doesn't fit, I'm OK with displaying as much as I can and the remainder (the overflow) being hidden.  That's what makes this hard and why I reached out.  I know this is possible as I've seen this.  I will add some pics of some Visual WebGUI code that does what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Figured it out.  Ditched div tables and used html tables.